# Cost at block number

Tags: blocks, price, explorer-api

Is their any API available that gets me the price of Eth in USD for example at a particular blocknumber?

Answer (score 1):

The price of Ethereum in terms of USD is not related to block numbers, as Ethereum to USD trading happens off-chain.  Exchanges and price aggregators such as [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/) may store historical prices and allow public read access to them.